# Can an object following 'own up to' be omitted?

Tags: verbs

> Tom finally owned up to stealing my bag.

In the sentence, I know 'own up to' is an expression as it is. 
In the expression, considering the meaning, I think an object could be implied, such as 'conscience'.

Is it acceptable to think so?

Comment: No, there is no implication of such an object. Incidentally, "owned up to" is not a constituent, since "to" belongs with "stealing my bag".

Comment: What do you mean by "an object could be implied"?  What do you mean by "such as 'conscience'"?  Are you asking whether "Tom finally owned up to" (with a stranded preposition) is a grammatically correct sentence?  Are you asking whether "Tom finally owned up" (with no "to" at all) is a grammatically correct sentence?  Are you asking whether "Tom finally owned up to his conscience" is semantically sensible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to state the object or it doesn't make sense; it is not implied here in English.  Your sentence above is how it would be said; no one would drop the object "my bag" from this sentence.  The subject "Tom" could be implicit if the statement were in the passive voice:

> Jack: "Well, Tom has finally admitted to the theft."
>
> Evariste: "Really?  Well, it's about time that it was *owned up
>   to*."

It would also be fine, in this instance, to say:

> "Well, it's about time that it *has been* owned up to."

The second one here uses the present perfect.  It's probably more correct to use the present perfect in this instance; however, 95% of speakers would probably use the simple past "was" in this instance.

Also, in your example, it is probably more correct to say it this way:

> "Tom *has* finally owned up to stealing the bag."

In this instance, the present perfect is used rather than the simple past; however, I think, in spoken English, most people would probably say it in the simple past just as you have written it above.

Comment: 99%" of native speakers wouldn't use the passive in this situation.

Comment: I don't know about 99%, but you're right; a lot wouldn't; however, he was asking for any way that he could drop the object from his sentence because he wanted it to be implicit. I told him no, he could not drop the object "my bag"; however, he could drop "Tom" as the indirect object if we reworded the sentence.